# What command can i use to check if a specified string in a file,if not, add it to the last of the file?

Tags: linux, shell

For example:
I want to check if "server proxy" exists in the file "aaa",

1. if YES, then there's nothing to be done;
2. if NOT, then I will add "server proxy" to the last new line of the file "aaa".

So how should I use shell command to realize it?

Ps. I think the command `tee -a` may give some help to the second step.

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -q "server proxy" aaa || echo "server proxy" >> aaa
```